# Running a Java Program Referencing OpenCV's Jar File

Tags: java, opencv, jar, compilation

I'm finding it impossible to run my program that's relying on the OpenCV jar file. I have compiled with "javac -cp opencv-300.jar *.java", but trying to run java Program meant it couldn't find the main class, so I ran with java Program.Program which threw exceptions regarding finding the OpenCV classes.

I tried java "-Djava.library.path=". -jar opencv-300.jar but that only returned "no main manifest attribute, in opencv-300.jar". I tried uncompiling the jar and running with java -cp . Program.Program and it returned "UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path", but that seems like a terrible path.

Does anybody have any clue how I can make the damn thing run? Trying on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS, with identical results on both. Please help!

Edit: I can upload a public Dropbox link so people can see for themselves if that would help.

Comment: In which package is your main ? Try 'java ... your.package.MainClass'

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing "Program.Program" was my example. The issue seems to be the OpenCV jar file and the fact that despite working during compile it appears to be of little help during execution.

Comment: You have all kind of dependency issues.  First you have a compile time dependency on the opencv-java300.jar.  Second you have runtime dependencies on that same jar, and that jar has runtime dependencies on the opencv native libs.  Have you tried setting up eclipse to work with opencv and running it from there?  That would be a good first step--there are guides for doing that.  And finally, Java packages should be named in all lower case.